# Scalamock 3 with Java Interface

Tags: scala, scalamock

I'm having trouble getting Scalamock 3 to mock a Java interface.  I'm
trying to run describeInstances on AWS.  The call requires an EC2
client which I mocked with the method described in the tutorial.
I get the error:

```
Error:(20, 42) type mismatch;
 found   : com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DescribeInstancesRequest
 required: org.scalamock.function.FunctionAdapter0[Boolean]
    (client.describeInstances _).expects(request).returning(result.withNextToken("1").withReservations(res1))
                                     ^
```

Do I need to do something special for a Java interface?

```
package example

import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.{ Instance, Reservation, DescribeInstancesRequest, DescribeInstancesResult }
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory

class ApiSpec extends FunSpec with MockFactory {

  describe("getInstances") {
    val client = mock[AmazonEC2]
    val request = new DescribeInstancesRequest
    val result = new DescribeInstancesResult
    val instance1 = (new Instance).withInstanceId("i-000")
    val instance2 = (new Instance).withInstanceId("i-000")
    val res1 = (new Reservation).withInstances(instance1)
    val res2 = (new Reservation).withInstances(instance2)
    (client.describeInstances _).expects(request).returning(result.withNextToken("1").withReservations(res1))
    (client.describeInstances _).expects(request.withNextToken("1")).returning(result.withReservations(res2))
  }

}
```

Comment: I would guess that an implicit is not being resolved properly, have you tried importing org.scalamock._ ?

Comment: Yeah, and wildcard imported all the other subpackages I could find...